# Is there no precise implementation of batch normalization in tensorflow and why?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

What is precisely done by **batch normalization at inference phase** is to normalize each layer with a population mean and an estimated population variance
[image]

But it seems every tensorflow implementation (including [this one](http://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html) and the official tensorflow [implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm)) uses **(exponential) moving average and variance**.

Please forgive me, but I don't understand why. Is it because using moving average is just better for performance? Or for a pure computational speed sake?

Refercence: [the original paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/ioffe15.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Exact update rule for sample mean is just an exponential averaging with a step equal to inverse sample size. So, if you know sample size, you could just set the decay factor to be `1/n`, where `n` is sample size. However, decay factor usually does not matter if chosen to be very close to one, as exponetital averaging with such decay rate still provides very close approximation of mean and variance, especially on large datasets.